# Controlling div visibility from toggle buttons on another page

Tags: wordpress, admin

I am looking to control the visibility of a div on one page from a toggle button on an admin page. I have seen many examples of this being done on the same page but none that explain what it would look like to have this done from another page.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to handle this. You should research what you want to do and then decide on a method that works best for you.

Personally I would look at a server-side implementation. In this way you can control the output to the client. You can use session variables for example. How this is done will depend on what language you are using.

If you only want a javascript solution then I can think of two options. First is to use cookies. You can then read the cookie and show/hide the div based on the value. This is what I would do.

Second you can pass in a querystring parameter and read it on the other page. Then hide/show your div. `http://mysite.com/?div=hidden`

Comment: I know this whole thing will take place in Wordpress and the admin page will be in the admin area of the wordpress site. More or less I want the admins of the site to be able to show or hide certain divs in the easiest way possible.  Thank you for answering by the way.

Comment: You should look into Wordpress themes then. WP is PHP based, so you will need to edit the default admin area theme files. You can then store the visibility setting in your WP installation and hide/show the div based on this setting. If you are not familiar with WP theming and PHP then this will not be easy for you. Check out http://wordpress.stackexchange.com. I am going to recommend this question be migrated there.

Comment: I was not aware of the wordpress.stckexchange.com I will take a look at it. However, I doubt that there are any themes with a show or hid div function built in. Have you ran across any?

Comment: @Philip - you will need to write your own modified theme. No, there won't be any themes with this built-in. Maybe a plugin exists. Or you could write your own plugin.

Comment: The plugins I have found are not used in the context of an admin making changes to the site from the backend. Thanks for your time...I think I have a lot more writing to do.

Answer (score 0):

If the admin page opened the child page using JavaScript then you can assign the window to a variable and control the contents through that variable. Like so:

```
var childWindow = window.open('some URL', options);
// now toggle the div in the child
var childDiv= childWindow.document.getElementById('your_div_id');
$(childDiv).toggle();
```

Comment: The page that contains the divs will not be opened by the admin page only controlled by it. If I understand what you are saying, the changes would not be visible to other users only the admin?

Comment: In that case the post by @mrtsherman is the best line of thinking to follow.